# Header is overlapping my scroll bar HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, header, scrollbar, overlapping

I'm trying to have my header/navbar be fixed at the top, but becasue of this, the right side of the header overlaps the scroll bar.
[image]

I did find a kind of temporary fix by chaning the width of the header to 99.2%, but would remain an issue when inspecting. Here's my CSS for the header/nav:

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff
}
nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2.8em 2em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 .4em;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    transition: .5s color;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

You can view the issue at [frankkreutzer.com](http://frankkreutzer.com)

Comment: can you please also share the HTML structure ? so we can recreate your issue. and please don't link to external sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 'body' overflow-x: hidden

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have a `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `html` and `body`. Place a `overflow-x: visible;` on the `body`.

```
body {
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok. so i checked your website ( do not link again to external sites, but instead make a working snippet here )

the problem is that you have `body,html { overflow-x:hidden }` that's why the scrollbar isn't visible beneath your header.

remove that and it will work fine